# Context for Code Review is not set correctly (probably, Team Project Collection)

Tags: tfs

When I am trying to request a code review, this is what I am getting on TFS and it doesn't allow me to send the code review.

```
Context for Code Review is not set correctly (probably, Team Project Collection)
```

any one have had this?

Comment: do you have files in multiple team projects checked out in the same workspace?

Comment: no, just one project.

Comment: Do you have team field configured? I.e. Not using area oath for Team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this message after a TFS upgrade (from 2012 to 2013 in my case).

In the TFS web portal there was a notification in the Overview tab of the Control Panel for my project. After clicking through the links on the wizard that popped up, I no longer had this issue.

Answer (score 8):

**Disconnect**. Then **Re-connect** to Team Projects

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me after I went offline and got disconnected from TFS server. I clicked on the plug icon in Team Explorer ribbon, and I was able to send the code review

Answer (score 1):

Same Issue. connection .

Afret re connect to TFS server. all went smoothly.